# Add decimals in a whole number

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, integer

I need some way to put decimals to a whole number based on their numbers in JavaScript.

Any ideas?

```
// Input:
const num1 = 73;
const num2 = 364;
const num3 = 7532;
const num4 = 75325;

function formatDecimals(num) {
  // Magic here
}

// Output:
console.log(formatDecimals(num1)); // 7.3
console.log(formatDecimals(num2)); // 3.64
console.log(formatDecimals(num3)); // 75.32
console.log(formatDecimals(num3)); // 753.25
```

Comment: Okay so what did you try? This seems like "do my homework"

Comment: what is the rule behind?

Comment: Why is it 3.64 and not 36.4?

Comment: So far I've tried a lot of things but nothing relevant. The truth I've been working an exaggerated amount of hours and my mind is no longer for this last thing haha.

Comment: Show your attempts....

Comment: If the number has 2 digits. It is separated in half.

If it has 3, its first digit is separated and 2 decimals are left.

If you have 4, separate 2 digits and leave 2 decimals.

If you have 5, separate 3 digits and leave 2 decimals.

Anyway, I am not going to need anything more than 4 digits. So don't get too complicated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the value and try to get at least one place, but for greater number only two places.

```js
function formatDecimals(num) {
    if (num < 10) return num;
    if (num < 100) return num / 10;
    return num / 100;
}

const num1 = 73;
const num2 = 364;
const num3 = 7532;
const num4 = 75325;

console.log(formatDecimals(num1)); //   7.3
console.log(formatDecimals(num2)); //   3.64
console.log(formatDecimals(num3)); //  75.32
console.log(formatDecimals(num4)); // 753.25
```